# GeoCoordinateWatcher position changed event is not trggering, while the app is not in foreground(ideal state)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a location based wp7 app, i need to update the location, if there any change in location.

I am using GeoCoordinateWatcher to get the location.

Its working fine, at position changed event triggering whenever the location change.

But position changed event not triggering at all, while the app is in ideal state.

how can i get the location update, while my app is not running in foreground, that means my app is in ideal state.

Can anybody give me a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get such thing. Windows Phone 7 suspends your application when it is not in the foreground. This is a limitation in the OS itself.

In Windows Phone 8 you can get such info when your application is running in background via Background Location services. Read more about it on MSDN:

- [How to continuously track the phone's location for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj247548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [How to run location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

EDIT:
While running, you can use lots of other API. To see which APIs can be used, check out [Features that can be used while running in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). It is possible to call web services in background tasks.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, is it possible to do that in 7.8sdk.

Comment: Hi

I decide to implement that background location tracking in wp8,

So I have upgraded my wp7.1 app into wp8,

I found a helping document here

How to run location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8

Its help full, but i need to call a web service at the location changed event,

    Is it possible to do web service call while the app is in  ideal state
    Can i get response from a web service call while the app is in  ideal state
    If possible can you please let me know how

Thank you.